# haskell: filtering Strings with a certain symbol e.g '!' in a List?

Tags: string, list, haskell

I have a list of Strings :
`["1*1", "ab!c", "cde2", "efghi!"]`
I want to sort out every string with an `'!'`.
My first idea was :
`filter (map elem '!' (list)) list` 
String with map elem '!' (list), but thats not really working because it only checkups the String as itself and not the elements of the Strings in that List...

thanks for your help!

Comment: it's almost right - indeed you have a bit to much ;) - hint: check the types for `elem`, `elem '!'` and `filter` and mind that `String = [Char]` ;D - btw: it's really helpful if you would mention what did not work for you (for example compiler errors, stuff going wrong), etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mapped too much.

```
filter ('!' `elem`) list
```

should work for you....

**Explanation:**

You have a list of strings `[String]`.
A string is a list of chars, because `String = [Char]`...

So basically you have a list of lists. `[[Char]]`
Since elem works by checking if a single element exists in a list, you can just call `elem` on each list item from your outer list.

Comment: yeah that is right - but most likely this question was homework and you should have waited a bit longer before spoiling - +1 anyway ^^

Comment: yeah but anyway that helped alot! Another question: how do i reverse the filter ? Well I want to return a list without Strings with "!",....

Comment: You _could_ use `not`...

If this is indeed homework, try defining your own function by composing `not` and `elem` together.

Comment: and how do i manage to filter '!', '?', '+' at the same time?